# WebSocket connection to 'wss://www.aniconnect.org/ws/chat/AUdZzo8slKKwKvzmUrnmLRfnVkuAYfJj/' failed:

Tags: javascript, django, ssl, websocket, django-channels

I have been working on a Django chatting application that uses websockets to implement its chatting functionality.
The site was working fine when it was being accessed through an IP address but when I tried to get an SSL certificate using letsencrypt, it broke.

I was following the guide at

> letsencrypt:
> https://certbot.eff.org/instructions?ws=nginx&os=ubuntufocal

Everything was going fine until I had to enter the `sudo certbot --nginx` command in the terminal which prompted me to enter a domain name, that I hadn't bought.

So before I bought a domain name, I tested the site and then it broke. The chatting functionality was no longer working but I thought that it was just part of getting an SSL certificate.

So I proceeded to buy a domain name. I managed to get the domain name set up properly but that error was not resolved. I even managed to get an SSL certificate for that domain name

Using the `sudo certbot --nginx` command. The websocket connection is unable to be established for some reason.

The following is the nginx config file:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.aniconnect.org;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name www.aniconnect.org;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.aniconnect.org/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.aniconnect.org/privkey.pem;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        alias /home/gamedeveloper/anime_chat/anime_chat_app/static/;
    }

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;
    }
    location /ws/ {
        proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme; # Set the protocol to 'https'
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Ssl on; # Enable SSL forwarding


        proxy_read_timeout 86400;
    }
}
```

Although it may be unrelated to the websocket connection failing, I am getting an error in my Gunicorn logs:

```
(venv) gamedeveloper@animechatapp:~$ sudo journalctl -u gunicorn
Sep 08 04:31:53 animechatapp systemd[1]: Started gunicorn.service - gunicorn daemon.
Sep 08 04:31:53 animechatapp gunicorn[286568]: [2023-09-08 04:31:53 +0000] [286568] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 21.2.0
Sep 08 04:31:53 animechatapp gunicorn[286568]: [2023-09-08 04:31:53 +0000] [286568] [INFO] Listening at: unix:/run/gunicorn.sock (286568)
Sep 08 04:31:53 animechatapp gunicorn[286568]: [2023-09-08 04:31:53 +0000] [286568] [INFO] Using worker: sync
Sep 08 04:31:53 animechatapp gunicorn[286569]: [2023-09-08 04:31:53 +0000] [286569] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 286569
Sep 08 04:31:53 animechatapp gunicorn[286570]: [2023-09-08 04:31:53 +0000] [286570] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 286570
Sep 08 04:31:53 animechatapp gunicorn[286571]: [2023-09-08 04:31:53 +0000] [286571] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 286571
Sep 08 04:31:53 animechatapp gunicorn[286570]: [2023-09-08 04:31:53 +0000] [286570] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
Sep 08 04:31:53 animechatapp gunicorn[286570]: Traceback (most recent call last):
Sep 08 04:31:53 animechatapp gunicorn[286570]:   File "/home/gamedeveloper/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 609, in spawn_worker
Sep 08 04:31:53 animechatapp gunicorn[286570]:     worker.init_process()
Sep 08 04:31:53 animechatapp gunicorn[286570]:   File "/home/gamedeveloper/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 134, in init_process
Sep 08 04:31:53 animechatapp gunicorn[286570]:     self.load_wsgi()
Sep 08 04:31:53 animechatapp gunicorn[286570]:   File "/home/gamedeveloper/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 146, in load_wsgi
Sep 08 04:31:53 animechatapp gunicorn[286570]:     self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
Sep 08 04:31:53 animechatapp gunicorn[286570]:                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Sep 08 04:31:53 animechatapp gunicorn[286570]:   File "/home/gamedeveloper/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
Sep 08 04:31:53 animechatapp gunicorn[286570]:     self.callable = self.load()
Sep 08 04:31:53 animechatapp gunicorn[286570]:                     ^^^^^^^^^^^
Sep 08 04:31:53 animechatapp gunicorn[286570]:   File "/home/gamedeveloper/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 58, in load
Sep 08 04:31:53 animechatapp gunicorn[286570]:     return self.load_wsgiapp()
Sep 08 04:31:53 animechatapp gunicorn[286570]:            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Sep 08 04:31:53 animechatapp gunicorn[286570]:   File "/home/gamedeveloper/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 48, in load_wsgiapp
Sep 08 04:31:53 animechatapp gunicorn[286570]:     return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
Sep 08 04:31:53 animechatapp gunicorn[286570]:            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Sep 08 04:31:53 animechatapp gunicorn[286570]:   File "/home/gamedeveloper/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 371, in import_app
Sep 08 04:31:53 animechatapp gunicorn[286570]:     mod = importlib.import_module(module)
Sep 08 04:31:53 animechatapp gunicorn[286570]:           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Sep 08 04:31:53 animechatapp gunicorn[286570]:   File "/usr/lib/python3.11/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
Sep 08 04:31:53 animechatapp gunicorn[286570]:     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
Sep 08 04:31:53 animechatapp gunicorn[286570]:            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Sep 08 04:31:53 animechatapp gunicorn[286570]:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1204, in _gcd_import
Sep 08 04:31:53 animechatapp gunicorn[286570]:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1176, in _find_and_load
Sep 08 04:31:53 animechatapp gunicorn[286570]:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1147, in _find_and_load_unlocked
Sep 08 04:31:53 animechatapp gunicorn[286570]:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 690, in _load_unlocked
Sep 08 04:31:53 animechatapp gunicorn[286570]:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 940, in exec_module
Sep 08 04:31:53 animechatapp gunicorn[286570]:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
Sep 08 04:31:53 animechatapp gunicorn[286570]:   File "/home/gamedeveloper/anime_chat/anime_chat_app/anime_chat_app/wsgi.py", line 16, in <module>
Sep 08 04:31:53 animechatapp gunicorn[286570]:     application = get_wsgi_application()
Sep 08 04:31:53 animechatapp gunicorn[286570]:                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Sep 08 04:31:53 animechatapp gunicorn[286570]:   File "/home/gamedeveloper/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 12, in get_wsgi_application
Sep 08 04:31:53 animechatapp gunicorn[286570]:     django.setup(set_prefix=False)
Sep 08 04:31:53 animechatapp gunicorn[286570]:   File "/home/gamedeveloper/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 19, in setup
Sep 08 04:31:53 animechatapp gunicorn[286570]:     configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)
Sep 08 04:31:53 animechatapp gunicorn[286570]:                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Sep 08 04:31:53 animechatapp gunicorn[286570]:   File "/home/gamedeveloper/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 102, in __getattr__
Sep 08 04:31:53 animechatapp gunicorn[286570]:     self._setup(name)
Sep 08 04:31:53 animechatapp gunicorn[286570]:   File "/home/gamedeveloper/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 89, in _setup
Sep 08 04:31:53 animechatapp gunicorn[286570]:     self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
Sep 08 04:31:53 animechatapp gunicorn[286570]:                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Sep 08 04:31:53 animechatapp gunicorn[286570]:   File "/home/gamedeveloper/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 217, in __init__
lines 1-51
```

Since that error is referring to my asgi.py file, here are its contents:

```
import os


from django.core.asgi import get_asgi_application


os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'anime_chat_app.settings')

django_asgi_app = get_asgi_application()


from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter, URLRouter
import common_anime_chat.routing

application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
    'http': django_asgi_app,
    'websocket': ProtocolTypeRouter({
        'http': get_asgi_application(),
        'websocket': URLRouter(
            common_anime_chat.routing.websocket_urlpatterns
        ),
    }),
})
```

I am also getting an error in my nginx error logs:

```
2023/10/09 04:09:30 [crit] 604871#604871: *1956 SSL_do_handshake() failed (SSL: error:0A00006C:SSL routines::bad key share) while SSL handshaking, client: some.ip.address, server: 0.0.0.0:443
2023/10/09 08:18:34 [crit] 604871#604871: *2044 SSL_do_handshake() failed (SSL: error:0A00006C:SSL routines::bad key share) while SSL handshaking, client: ome.ip.address, server: 0.0.0.0:443
```

The following is the JS code I am using to establish the connection with the websocket:

```
   const chatSocket = new WebSocket(
    (window.location.protocol === 'https:' ? 'wss://' : 'ws://') +
    window.location.host +
    '/ws/chat/' +
    roomName +
    '/'
);
```

The following is the routing.py file:

```
from django.urls import re_path
from . import consumers

websocket_urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r'^ws/chat/(?P<room_name>\w+)/$', consumers.ChatRoomConsumer.as_asgi())
]
```

Please help me out with this problem!